# content inside the span are hiding the parent when span is growing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a html and css designed in this way.

```css
.sectionTitle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e8eaed;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}


/*class from global css file */

.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*this class are modification in the component itself */

.contentAlignment {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSpacing col-12">
  <!---->
  <div>
    <!---->
    <div class="sectionTitle d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <label class="formLabelStyles sectionheading">References</label>
    </div>

    <!---->
    <div>
      <!---->
      <div class="contentAlignment">
        <span style="font-size: 48px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Middle Cerebral Artery</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<span>` element inside the `div` having the class `contentAlignment` are dynamic content for which I don't have the control, and it should be displayed exactly how the user has setup.

If those content have large font size it will overflow the parent div. The parent div are hidden.

How to fix this particular issue?

Edit:

I had also tried by changing the

```
.contentAlignment {
  line-height: 0
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

But it is not working, because removing the line-height completely from this class only then it works.

```
.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Problem here is i couldn't remove the line-height from `global.css` and it is the global file which is used in all the pages, removing the line height may create the problem in other components.

Comment: if I understand correctly, can't you just remove `line-height: 23px`? this is what makes the red `.contentAlignment` overflow and hide `.sectionTitle` behind itself. the default `line-height` property will automatically adjust to the font-size if you leave it be.

Comment: line height was set from the global css file, so removing it would also could effect other file where it has been used. So, I set the `line-height: 0;` but it didn't work.

Comment: use `line-height: normal`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because line-height is set as px instead of relative to the font size. (The font size should also be in rem or em and not px, but that's unrelated to this issue).

I also removed the CSS that was overwritten anyway.

```css
.sectionTitle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e8eaed;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.contentAlignment {
  line-height: 1.35;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSpacing col-12">
  <!---->
  <div>
    <!---->
    <div class="sectionTitle d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <label class="formLabelStyles sectionheading">References</label>
    </div>

    <!---->
    <div>
      <!---->
      <div class="contentAlignment">
        <span style="font-size: 48px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Middle Cerebral Artery</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: line height was set from the global css file, so removing it would also could effect other file where it has been used. So, I set the line-height: 0; but it didn't work.

Comment: @AkshayKriti I'm not talking about removing it or setting it to 0, I set it to 1.35. If that causes conflict, have you tried adding a class specifically for that div element and setting the line-height in that?

Comment: i have added the line-height in the contentAlignment

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using a fixed line height in your style sheet. The result is that you are increasing the font size while keeping the `line_height: 23px`

In this case you should just remove the line-height

```css
.sectionTitle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e8eaed;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.contentAlignment {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSpacing col-12">
  <!---->
  <div>
    <!---->
    <div class="sectionTitle d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <label class="formLabelStyles sectionheading">References</label>
    </div>

    <!---->
    <div>
      <!---->
      <div class="contentAlignment">
        <span style="font-size: 48px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Middle Cerebral Artery</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: line height was set from the global css file, so removing it would also could effect other file where it has been used. So, I set the line-height: 0; but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to `line-height: 23px`, which doesn't match the set `font-size` (in this case, `43px`).

Just apply `line-height: normal` to the `.contentAlignment`-class. As long as the `line-height` specified by whatever other source isn't more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), it should work. Also, `line-height: normal` has to be read **after** `line-height: 23px`, as CSS is read from top to bottom. If your selector is more specific though, this shouldn't be an issue.

You can see my example I've applied `line-height: normal` **after** `line-height: 23px`, which overrides the former `line-height`. Just remember this logic applies to stylesheets as well, so make sure the stylesheet thats applying `line-height: normal` is read after the one thats applying `line-height: 23px` (unless your selector is more specific).

```css
.sectionTitle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e8eaed;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}


/*class from global css file */

.contentAlignment {
  /* doesn't work - it's overwritten */
  line-height: normal;
}

div.contentAlignment {
  /* works - is more specific than just .contentAlignment */
  line-height: normal;
}


.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* works - overrides the line-height */
  line-height: normal;
}

.contentAlignment {
  /* works - overrides the line-height */
  line-height: normal;
}

/*this class are modification in the component itself */

.contentAlignment {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.contentAlignment {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionSpacing col-12">
  <!---->
  <div>
    <!---->
    <div class="sectionTitle d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <label class="formLabelStyles sectionheading">References</label>
    </div>

    <!---->
    <div>
      <!---->
      <div class="contentAlignment">
        <span style="font-size: 48px; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Middle Cerebral Artery</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```